# Spring-Boot JPA-Hibernate Liquibase: how to populate PostgreSQL DB taking into account the changes of the entity?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using Spring-Boot 1.5.12 with JPA and Hibernate.
The database I'm using is PostgreSQL. Right now I'm populating the DB with a **data.sql** file within `src/main/resources`.
It's working fine, however since I'm using Liquibase too in order to keep track of the changes in the DB, I would need to be able to automatically update the insert statements in the **SQL**, for example in the case some fields get removed from an entity. Is there a way to do this by mixing the features of hibernate and liquibase?

If not, the only solution I'm able to think for doing this in a semi-automated way, with the help of the compiler and Java strong typing, is the following EJB:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class Initializer {
    @PostConstruct
    public void populate() {
        //initialize database here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Liquibase to insert the data? I typically use a CSV file within a single changeset using `runOnChange="true"` that is loaded `<loadUpdateData>`. Liquibase will then automatically run the changeset if the input file changes. But you would still need to adjust the input file to the new table structure (at least if you want to populate the new columns with the default data)

Comment: May I have an example of the steps needed to do it this way? Ok, so would I still need to update the CSV file each time? It would be good to have liquibase, once detected the changes, use a default value or `null` for **new fields** and just remove the no more existing column fields from the CSV.

Comment: New columns are not a problem. If you define the appropriate default value when adding the column you don't need to touch the CSV. Of course if you remove a column, you have to remove that from the CSV as well